# Mixed vs Fixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, random-variable, random-effects-model, model

I'm currently weighing up the most appropriate of two models, one including individual as a random effect and the other discarding it: -

1. `~score + (1|individual) + region`
2. `~score + region`

`score` is a continuous/numeric variable and represents a measure of disease severity in a piece of tissue, `individual` is the unique individual identifier, and `region` is one of two regions the tissue was obtained from within the same organ.

The underlying data is hundreds of measurements of a gene's activity from individual cells within that particular sample of tissue.  The purpose of the model is to understand if the activity of the gene changes with the disease severity score.  There are 11 individuals and 22 samples.  Overall, the available data is as below (with n representing the number of observations/cells/values from each sample): -

| individual | region | score | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 0.490 | 310 |
| A | Y | 0.293 | 520 |
| B | X | 0.334 | 105 |
| B | Y | 1.377 | 272 |
| C | X | 0.299 | 224 |
| C | Y | 0.261 | 321 |
| D | X | 0.740 | 338 |
| D | Y | 0.322 | 273 |
| E | X | 1.588 | 115 |
| E | Y | 2.327 | 297 |
| F | X | 1.753 | 397 |
| F | Y | 3.288 | 606 |
| G | X | 0.059 | 508 |
| G | Y | 0.297 | 350 |
| H | X | 0.462 | 189 |
| H | Y | 0.337 | 127 |
| I | X | 1.247 | 290 |
| I | Y | 0.769 | 721 |
| J | X | 0.889 | 269 |
| J | Y | 0.646 | 316 |
| K | X | 0.740 | 545 |
| K | Y | 0.204 | 537 |

My initial thought was to include the `(1|individual)` term as in model 1; however, I have some reservations.

Firstly, the disease severity score is unique for each sample, e.g. the only observations of a disease severity score of 0.490 are the 310 cells from region X of individual A.  I'm concerned that while this first model seems to account for the relatedness/possible correlations between samples from the same individual, the co-linearity between the score and individual may undermine the results.  Secondly, the second model's performance (excluding the individual effect) is superior when validated against a new dataset of unseen individuals.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which one of the variables in the table is the outcome/response ?

Comment: For brevity, I've omitted the outcome/response data here.  Essentially, there are hundreds of values for each sample (e.g. there are 310 outcome/response numbers for the sample from individual A and region X, etc.).  Each of those 310 numbers represents a reading from a single individual cell from that particular sample.

Comment: OK , so if I'm understanding this correctly, `score` is 100% collinear with the `region:individual` combination ? Each individual has 2 and only 2 scores, one for region X and one for region Y. Is that right ?

Comment: That's correct, `score` is 100% colinear with the `region:individual` combination, and each unique `region:individual` combination has a few hundred observations.

Comment: And yes, each individual has 2 and only 2 scores, one for region X and one for region Y.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about the out-of-sample testing that you did ? [*the second model's performance (excluding the individual effect) is superior when validated against a new dataset of unseen individuals.*].

Comment: The model was applied separately to each gene (~20,000 genes) in this main cohort, producing a list of significant genes (i.e. a subset of ~200 genes with p<0.05 that the gene activity/outcome/response was correlated with the disease severity `score`).  The same method was applied to a separate test cohort of six individuals (12 samples).  The overlap of the two gene sets was examined to evaluate the "reproducibility".

Comment: The model without the `(1|individual)` term performed better:  ~60% of the significant genes identified in the main cohort were identified also as significant in the test cohort, while this proportion was only ~25% using the model with the `(1|individual)` term.

Comment: @RobertLong do you have any sense at all of whether the `(1|individual)` term can be dropped from this model?  Worried it won't get past reviewers without it, but it seems detrimental to the model's performance when it's included!