# Mixed or Fixed Effect Model for this data?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, random-effects-model

I recently asked for some assistance with selecting an optimal model for genetic data, but feel the inclusion of too many details may have resulted in a lack of responses (see: [Mixed vs Fixed effects model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/509238/mixed-vs-fixed-effects-model?noredirect=1#comment940593_509238)).  I hope that this simplified example may help to solicit more responses.

Suppose that we wish to evaluate whether treating the leaves of plants with chemical X causes the leaves to grow or shrink.  We have six plants and test 12 doses, so split each into the left side and the right side.

[image: Expt design]

Five leaves on each side of the plant are then painted with a single dose of the chemical: -

| plant | region | dose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | L | 0 |
| A | R | 1 |
| B | L | 2 |
| B | R | 3 |
| C | L | 4 |
| C | R | 5 |
| D | L | 6 |
| D | R | 7 |
| E | L | 8 |
| E | R | 9 |
| F | L | 10 |
| F | R | 11 |

After one month, the change in leaf size is quantified and a model is fit.

Two questions: -

One)
Which of the following models would you fit on the `growth` data?

1. `~dose + (1|plant_id) + region`
2. `~dose + region`

Two)
Do you anticipate that in the mixed model, the inclusion of a random term for plant id (i.e. A,B,C,D,E,F) as a confounder may be problematic given that the two regions of the plant receive different doses?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

In this experiment you make repeated measures on each plant - each plant is measured twice, the left side and the right side. Due to this, measurements taken on one plant are likely to be more similar to the other measurement on the same plant, than measures on a different plant. This clustering means that observations are not independent and unless you account for this somehow, you are likely to obtain biased results.

One way to account for this non-independence is by fitting random intercepts for plant, as per your model 1. Another approach is to fit plant ID as a fixed effect

```
response ~ dose + plant_id + region
```

However if you have a lot of plants this will result in a lot of extraneous output and also suffers from lower statistical power due to each plant consuming a degree of freedom.

Comment: Thanks, Robert, this makes sense.  Just a couple of follow up questions: does the use of a fixed effect for the plant_id change the interpretation of the results?  Also, is there a general rule about how many n plants are reasonable with a fixed effect for plant_id before using a random effect is considered more appropriate?  How does that change with additional confounders (e.g. plant species, or say `sex` in human subjects)?  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcom. If it's a LMM (not a GLMM) then the interpretation of `dose` and `region` is the same. There are various rules of thumb about how many levels are needed before it's OK  to use random effects. There is some consensus around 6. Fewer than 6 and you should fit fixed effects, 6 or more and you could use random intercepts. If you are unsure, then fit two models. The addition of other fixed effects does not affect this.